# Qt - Get hostname & MAC address from IP Adreess

Tags: c++, qt, ip, mac-address, hostname

In my application I want to get the hostname & MAC address from an IP address (in my LAN).
I used this code to find the hostname, but nothing appeared in lineedit.

```
QHostInfo HI;
QHostAddress HA("192.168.1.1");
QList<QHostAddress> List;
List.append(HA);
HI.setAddresses(List);
ui->ledHostname->setText(HI.hostName());
```

Comment: Probably too late for you, but surely very useful for someone still looking on how to get remote PC MAC address using Qt (**for Windows**): [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52814472/4731718) Cheers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this code:

```
QHostInfo HI = QHostInfo::fromName("192.168.1.50");
ui->ledHostname->setText(HI.hostName());
```

Worked for some ip addresses & shows the host name! For other ip addresses shows the ip address again.

For my MAC problem, I`m using ARP packet.

Answer (score 2):

To retrieve the Hostname from an IP address you can call lookupHost(), which takes the host name or IP address, a receiver object, and a slot signature as arguments. The slot is invoked when the results are ready. The results are stored in a QHostInfo object. Call addresses() to get the list of IP addresses for the host, and hostName() to get the host name that was looked up.

```
QHostInfo::lookupHost("92.168.1.1",
                   this, SLOT(lookedUp(QHostInfo)));

void MyWidget::lookedUp(const QHostInfo &host)
 {
     if (host.error() != QHostInfo::NoError) {
         qDebug() << "Lookup failed:" << host.errorString();
         return;
     }

     foreach (const QHostAddress &address, host.addresses())
         qDebug() << "Found address:" << address.toString();
 }
```

For obtaining the MAC address of a remote IP you should use system commands and platform-specific code. There is no way in Qt to do that. For example on Windows it can be done by:

```
arp -a <IP>
```

Comment: Thanks dear Nejat.
These code says "Found Address:" even the IP address is not lived (not connect!)

Comment: Thanks for the link but when I set ip address & run the application, it returns the ip address again! (Not hostname)

I tested by "192.168.1.1" & a valid ip address. (did not work!)

Comment: "I made some edits to the answer." Those are wrong edits. The host name lookup has *nothing to do whatosever* with whether a given host is "live" or not. The platform-specific host lookup will *also succeed* on a disconnected host, unless some form of dynamic DNS was in use, and the cached address has already expired. Similarly, an `arp` command doesn't need a live host - the OS will cache ARP results.

Comment: @MohammadRezaRamezani "These code says "Found Address:" even the IP address is not lived (not connect!)" That's the expected, *correct* behavior. The host lookup can succeed whether the host is attached or not. You need a different way of determining if the host is present. For example, by pinging it.